# Setting phone ringtone via NFC in Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, nfc

is it possible to switch off phone ringtone or better, setting a custom profile, via NFC using Windows Phone 8 API ?

Answer (score 2):

That's not a built-in capability of WP8. You could build an app that adds a ringtone. First, you'll need to [create a custom protocol](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/What%27s_new_in_Windows_Phone_8#App2app%3a_Custom_protocols) for your app (e.g. "addRingtone://foo"). Next, you'll need to add intercept that deeplink and invoke the [SaveRingTask](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh394008%28v=vs.105%29.aspx).